# Java/Kotlin/Android - format time (hh:mm:ss) and remove unnecessary zeros from the beginning

Tags: java, android, kotlin, format, string-formatting

My application displays time left in such format hh:mm:ss, for example, 01:05:45 what stands for one hour 5 minutes and 45 seconds.

When hours or minutes are zero I would like not to display them. Currently, if 45 seconds are remaining my timer will show '00:00:45'. The expected result is just '45'.

I need some kind of Java/Kotlin/Android method to produce the following outputs:

- 1 hour 13 minutes and 10 seconds  ==>  01:13:10
- 0 hours 13 minutes and 10 seconds  ==> 13:10
- 3 hours 0 minutes and 16 seconds  ==> 03:00:16
- 0 hour 0 minutes and 5 seconds  ==>  5

Currently I use such string as a formatter:

```
<string name="time_default_formatter" translatable="false">%02d:%02d:%02d</string>
```

I tried to manually replace string "00:" with "" but it fails when it comes to a 3rd example. Also, I think standard formatting should provide something like that but I keep failing to find it.

Edit: I can do it in code. The thing is I am looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: Is this a hard requirement? Most electronic timers and timer apps do include at least the minutes, even if zero.

Comment: It is a hard requirement I'm afraid. The client saw such a solution in a few timer apps and he wants the same thing.

Comment: In that case you're probably going to need conditional logic to select from different formats or concatenate only the relevant fields.

Comment: I will do so if I must. Yet I hope there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: So you need a formatting pattern or code?

Comment: Just check if it's > 1min or > 1h and change the format string accordingly?

Comment: @forpas I know how to do it with code. I seek an elegant solution.

Comment: @MichałPowłoka How is code not an "elegant solution"? I don't think any solution in XML alone (which I don't think is possible) will be any more elegant.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

String resources are meant for displaying actual text in a way that is easily localizable. They aren't meant for formatting dates and times; that's what [`DateUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils) is for.

> This class contains various date-related utilities for creating text
> for things like elapsed time and date ranges, strings for days of the
> week and months, and AM/PM text etc.

Which comes with a convenient [`formatElapsedTime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatElapsedTime(long)) method that formats a duration as you would expect.

> Formats an elapsed time in the form "MM:SS" or "H:MM:SS"…

Unfortunately the last format you mentioned (which only displays seconds) is fairly uncommon, therefore unsupported by `DateUtils`. Though this can be easily remedied with the following function.

```
fun formatDuration(seconds: Long): String = if (seconds < 60) {
    seconds.toString()
} else {
    DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(seconds)
}
```

Comment: Works like a dream. That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use kotlin Duration with toComponents to get the individual parts.

```
fun formatDurationTime(durationSeconds: Long) =
    durationSeconds.seconds.toComponents { hours, minutes, seconds, _ ->
        String.format(
            Locale.getDefault(),
            "%02d:%02d:%02d",
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So far I haven't found any elegant in my opinion solution and I do it like that.

I have three formatting strings, one for each situation:

```
<string name="time_hours_minutes_seconds_formatter" translatable="false">%02d:%02d:%02d</string>
<string name="time_minutes_seconds_formatter" translatable="false">%02d:%02d</string>
<string name="time_seconds_formatter" translatable="false">%02d</string>
```

Then, manually I format it using function (in Kotlin):

```
    private fun formatTime(millis: Long): String {
    val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) % 24
    val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % 60
    val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % 60

    return when {
        hours == 0L && minutes == 0L -> String.format(
            resources.getString(R.string.time_seconds_formatter), seconds
        )

        hours == 0L && minutes > 0L -> String.format(
            resources.getString(R.string.time_minutes_seconds_formatter), minutes, seconds
        )

        else -> resources.getString(R.string.time_hours_minutes_seconds_formatter, hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
android.text.format.DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(...)
```

for kotlin:

```
import java.util.Formatter

fun formatDurationTime(durationSeconds: Long): String {
    var hours = 0L
    var minutes = 0L
    var seconds = durationSeconds
    if (seconds >= 3600) {
        hours = seconds / 3600
        seconds -= hours * 3600
    }
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        minutes = seconds / 60
        seconds -= minutes * 60
    }
    return Formatter().format("%1\$02d:%2\$02d:%3\$02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString()
}
```